# numpy multidimensional array indexing

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a strange issue when I am doing indexing in a numpy multidimensional array. So, I have an array of shape (4, 882). I have another array called matches of shape (276, 2). This match array holds indexes of valid entries in my original multidimensional array. What I would like to do is select the first 2 rows and all the columns matching the indexes in the match array. So, I do something as follows:

```
import numpy as np
k = get_array()  # This has shape (4, 882)
m = get_match()  # This has shape (276, 2)

s = k[[1, 0], m[:, 0]]
```

This raises the error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

However, when I do:

```
s = k[[1, 0], :][:, m[:, 0]]
```

This works fine. So, this is in effect selecting the subset of rows first and then the columns but I am not sure why my first attempt is wrong. Also, doing:

```
s = k[[1, 0], :]
```

of course works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a little confusing because the shape mismatch isn't between `k` and `m`. It's between `[1, 0]` and `m[:,0]`. Here are three ways to fix it, using the following (more easily visualizable) arrays:

```
>>> k
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
>>> m
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

1. Change the indexing list to a 2-d list with a shape that can be *broadcasted* against `m`:

   ```
   >>> k[[[1], [0]],m[:, 0]]
   array([[ 8, 10, 12, 14],
          [ 0,  2,  4,  6]])
   ```
2. Convert it to an array and reshape the array:

   ```
   >>> k[numpy.array([1, 0]).reshape(2, 1),m[:, 0]]
   array([[ 8, 10, 12, 14],
          [ 0,  2,  4,  6]])
   ```
3. Convert it to an array and slice it using `numpy.newaxis`, a.k.a. `None`:

   ```
   >>> k[numpy.array([1, 0])[:,None],m[:, 0]]
   array([[ 8, 10, 12, 14],
          [ 0,  2,  4,  6]])
   ```

There are many others, but these are the three that come most readily to mind.

You're getting an error because `numpy` needs indices passed in this way to have the same shape, or to be broadcastable to the same shape. By making the `[1, 0]` list a "column array," you make them broadcastable. The same thing happens when you try to multiply `m` by `[1, 0]`:

```
>>> m[:,0] * [0, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

And all the same fixes apply. For example:

```
>>> m[:,0] * [[0], [1]]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 4, 6]])
```

Finally, note that you could also fix it by passing a differently-shaped slice of `m` -- observe that the output is transposed:

```
>>> k[[1, 0],m[:, 0:1]]
array([[ 8,  0],
       [10,  2],
       [12,  4],
       [14,  6]])
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much for that detailed answer... I had been scratching my head for an hour about this, at least!

Comment: This is described as 'advanced indexing' in the documentation.